# Concatenate Excel cell value from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I have just starting to use excel (to do something other than just open csv files)

I have Sheet1 and Sheet2.
Sheet1!A1 is `"1"`

In Sheet2 A1 I would like to have

`<myelement myattribute="1"/>`

I have tried concatenating using `&` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following formula

`="<myelement myattribute="&char(34)&text(Sheet1!A1,"0")&char(34)&"/>"`

- Char(34) meaning "
- Text(Number, Format) converts the number to a string